# Meaning of "reel" in songs?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs, vocabulary, lyrics

I feel like the word reel occurs often in Irish folk songs. Does it refer to turning around as in dancing? Is there used the same meaning as in There's a reason?

> So let that feeling
>
> Grap you deep inside
>
> And send you ***reeling***
>
> Where your love can't hide
>
> And then go stealing
>
> Through the summer nights
>
> With your lover

Naturally, I would assume it refers to opening to the world (like a string reels off a reel).

https://youtu.be/IDNbvwlRu6I

Comment: Your natural assumption is based on incomplete knowledge of the word **reel**, which exists both as a noun and as a verb.  You should really have looked this word up in a couple of *good* dictionaries first.   A punch in the jaw can **send you reeling**. Too much strong drink can send you reeling. Love can send you reeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *reel* is an Irish (or Scottish) folk dance that is danced to music with the same name, which is why you hear it often when listening to folk songs.

*[To reel](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reel)* is to stagger, feel unstable or intoxicated. It is used in the lyrics to describe the feeling of love.

Comment: and of other intoxicants.

Comment: In context of the song? I'm not in the position to listen to it right now.

Comment: I meant "the lyrics of Irish folk songs" generally.

Answer (score 1):

*"To send you reeling"* in those lyrics refers to the giddy/crazy feeling you get when you are in love. *Reeling* is being used figuratively in the sense of whirling.  In other contexts it can refer to a feeling of dizziness, shock, bewilderment, confusion, disarray, physically/mentally staggering

Other examples:

*I was sent reeling by her admission of guilt.*

*My mind was sent reeling when the doctor revealed I had a terminal illness.*

*The government was sent reeling after the scandal was reported in the media.*

The other meaning of *reel* which you alluded to, is a kind of dance popular in Scotland and Ireland. The dance originated in Scotland.  The noun is derived from the verb *to reel*, in the sense of whirling/spinning.